# How to automate angular components creation using ASP.NET with angular project in visual studio 2017

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, angular-components

I'm recently trying the new JavaScript Services for visual studio 2017.

I was used to use `Angular CLI` to create Angular project and then create componentes with `ng generate component` command.

However I tried the new ASP.NET Core Angular project that was released in visual studio that wonderfully integrates Client side angular or react project with the ASP.NET Core backend.

I didn't find a way to create angular components other than manually. I even tried using the Angular CLI command without success because the project was not generated using the Angular CLI.

I know that this tool is very young yet. But is there a way to automate process like generate new components and so on ?